# Error calculating area "IndexError: too many indices for tensor of dimension 1"

Tags: python, pytorch, object-detection

I'm repurposing some code from [here](https://github.com/microsoft/computervision-recipes/blob/master/utils_cv/detection/dataset.py) to perform object detection:

```
# Create boxes list
boxes = [
    [annotation['xmin'], annotation['ymin'], annotation['xmax'], annotation['ymax']]
    for annotation in image_annotations
]

...

area = (boxes[:, 3] - boxes[:, 1]) * (boxes[:, 2] - boxes[:, 0])
```

During training, I was hitting this error:

```
  File "c:\2021-mcm-master\src\PyTorch-RCNN\ui-prediction\src\screenshot_dataset.py", line 94, in __getitem__
    area = (boxes[:, 3] - boxes[:, 1]) * (boxes[:, 2] - boxes[:, 0])
IndexError: too many indices for tensor of dimension 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following a suggestion [here](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/calculating-bounding-box-area-indexerror-too-many-indices-for-tensor-of-dimension-1/78418), I discovered some of my images did not contain any bounding boxes and was causing this error:

```
# Create boxes list
boxes = [
    [annotation['xmin'], annotation['ymin'], annotation['xmax'], annotation['ymax']]
    for annotation in image_annotations
]

if len(boxes) == 0:
    print ("Help!")
```